# How put translations loader in argument of service in services.xml - Symfony 3

Tags: xml, symfony

I have definition in services.xml

```
<service id="app_bundle.importer.file" class="%app_bundle.importer.file.class%">
            <argument type="collection"></argument><!-- translation loaders -->
            <argument type="service" id="app_bundle.translation_storage" />
            <argument type="service" id="app_bundle.trans_unit.manager" />
            <argument type="service" id="app_bundle.file.manager" />
            <call method="setCaseInsensitiveInsert">
                <argument>%app_bundle.importer.case_insensitive%</argument>
            </call>
        </service>
```

I want this instance to have the first parameters loaders for translations file format, example:

```
Array
(
    ...

    [yml] => Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\YamlFileLoader Object
        (
            [yamlParser:Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\YamlFileLoader:private] => 
        )

    [xlf] => Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader Object
        (
        )

    [xliff] => Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader Object
            (
            )
    ...
)
```

How put this array automaticaly in argument from service?

Answer (score 0):

To inject an array :

```
<parameter key="myArray" type="collection">
  <parameter>item1</parameter>
  <parameter>item2</parameter>
</parameter>

<services>
    <service id="my.service" class="AppBundle\MyService">
        <argument>%myArray%</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html#component-di-parameters-array